# Accounts with open cases

Tags: case

We are working with a contact with an open case. We do not want business development calling this contact whilst there is a case open and attached to an account. 
How do we restrict access to accounts with open cases?

Answer (score 1):

While it is theoretically possible to build an Apex-managed sharing solution that would selectively share only those Contacts that do not have Cases to your Business Development team while hiding all others, that solution is so complex and so expensive that I would not recommend it under hardly any circumstances. Additionally, its applicability is dependent upon a variety of features of your org's sharing infrastructure, to such an extent that you'd really need to work with a skilled developer or consultant to evaluate whether it's even possible.

A far easier approach would be to use Declarative Lookup Rollups Summaries or a similar package to place a count of open Cases in a field on the Contact. You could then replace the Phone field on the Contact with a formula that only shows the real Phone value if the Case count is zero:

```
IF(Open_Cases__c > 0, 'Do Not Call - Open Cases', Phone)
```

There are a variety of other solutions possible, contingent upon exactly what you need to do, your existing sharing architecture, whether you're using Lightning Experience or Classic, and so forth, but that would be one approach that is clean, simple, and inexpensive.

You can surface that formula field in place of the Phone field on a page layout specific to your Business Development profile to ensure that all other users continue to see their expected data.

Comment: this is pretty clever